# How make when click marker scroll to sidebar item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I want, when user click marker, sidebar scrolling the item what user click..like this web https://googlemaps.github.io/js-store-locator/examples/places.html
....but how do this? any idea thanks..

**This div with map id & side_bar id.**

```
 <div style="width:100%; height:100vh;padding-bottom: 50px; ">
    <div id="map" style="top:50px;height:100%;width:80%;float:left"></div>
    <div id="side_bar" style="top:50px;width:20%;float:left;overflow-y: scroll; height:100%;margin-top:50px;padding:20px"></div> 
</div><!-- Map Ends display -->
```

**Add infowindow click from php data & add item in side_bar id**

```
     // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        map: map,
        visible: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon : icons[locations[i][4]],                  
      });

    // Event that closes the Info Window with a click on the map
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });      

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    })(marker, i));   

    markers.push(marker);

    var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markers["+parseInt(markers.length-1)+"],\"click\");'style='text-decoration:none;'>"+locations[i][0]+"</a><br><hr><br>";
     document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += side_bar_html;

   }
```

Comment: all the code you require is on the linked page. Read it

Comment: hallo @RachelGallen yes can you help me from my code...because when I follow the page my code error..thanks

Comment: your code is nothing like the example given. in the example you can also click on marker. If you want the items to scroll, give sidebar a fixed height and overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: @RachelGallen yes I add  overflow-y:scroll; on style...I edit sample like this link [link](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-store-locator/examples/places.html) . thanks

Comment: Great! Looks wonderful. Feel free to upvote one of my answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I add This

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);

       var no = marker.id;

      $("div[class*='item']").removeClass("active");
      $('div[class*=item_'+no+']').addClass("active");

      var $selectedLocation = $('div[class*=item_'+no+']' );  
      var $container = $('#side_bar');
      $container.animate({
        scrollTop: $selectedLocation.offset().top - $container.offset().top + $container.scrollTop()
      }); 
    }
    })(marker, i));
```

and add to my id marker